# Buttons - Column visibility in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, datatable, visibility

i used Button Column visibility in datatable with used of State saving. so user can save selected column.

but the issue is that when multiple user use same datatable and they select column as per their choice then it effect other user's selected column when they login again.

so i want Button Column visibility in datatable as per user.

suppose there is datatable named "product" and it have 5 column.And there are also 2 user use the same "product" datatable. "USER1" select column(1,3,5) and "USER2" select column(2,3,4,5). now when they login again then they can show their own selected column like "USER1" can see column(1,3,5) and "USER2" can see column(2,3,4,5).
my project is in spring boot.

is this possible in datatable in anyway?

Comment: Well since they "login" then i assume you have a database, would it not be best then to save the information in the database and then use that to show what you want?. Anyway without code it's a very broad question.

Comment: yes, you are right, but in my spring boot project, there are 60 different datatables. and it's a little difficult to manage. and if you know about that then can you suggest to me how to manage that way.